# 2000s space film where an alien species has almost wiped out the human race in a war

Tags: story-identification, movie

I need to find a film that I watched when I was a kid in 2000-2004 (don't remember the exact time). I remember the film about a person telling a story to his kids.

The story is about the fight between the human race with an alien species (which had something like coral attach to their head). The human race is almost annihilated. They lost every fight but keep fighting to the last man. But the alien stop the attack (don't remember why) and the humans build something like a satellite.

Some others thing I remember but not sure:

- Spaceship like *Star Trek*.
- Alien spaceships have 4 legs?
- There was another alien race want to stop the war but failed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/219906/31936) is correct.  I also immediately thought of the television series *Babylon 5* (1993-1999).

But the question includes:

> I need to find a film that I watched when I was a kid in 2000-2004 (don't remember the exact time). I remember the film about a person telling a story to his kids.

So someoneuseless remembers seeing a specific movie or a specific single episode where someone tells children the story of the the Human-Mimbari War.   And I think that if they watched the television series they would have remembered the details much more clearly.

Thus it is my guess that they remember seeing either the first broadcast or a later one of the television movie  *Babylon 5: In the Beginning* (January 4, 1998).

The synopsis in the Wikipedia article says:

> ...In 2278, Centauri Prime is in flames. A man surveys the destruction from a window of the Royal Palace. Two children, Luc and Lyssa, are later seen playing in the throne room and looking out the window. Their governess finds them and tells them that it is the Emperor's window and that only he can look out from it. The Emperor hears them and tells them to come in front of him. The Emperor is an aged Londo Mollari. Mollari allows Luc to be Emperor of the Centauri Republic for five minutes, during which time he may give any order he wishes. Luc asks for a story of great battles and heroes and villains. Lyssa wants to hear a true story. Mollari decides to give them both what they want and tell them the story of the Earth–Minbari War that took place 35 years prior while he was ambassador to Earth...

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5:_In_the_Beginning[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5:_In_the_Beginning%5B1%5D)

So the story teller is not telling it to his own children, although he might be acquainted with them if they are high ranking enough to be allowed to play in the imperial palace.  By the way, the Centauri characters in this frame story are not human, they just happen by chance to look a lot of humans - though one episode of the series suggests that Centauri look a lot less human without their clothes.

And Mollari tells the kids the story of the Earth-Mimbari War which includes all the details which someoneuseless included in their question.

And thus it is my guess that someoneuseless remembers watching *Babylon 5: In the Beginning*.

And if they are interested in watching *Babylon 5*, one of the greatest science fiction shows of all time, maybe someone could point them to some discussion of the proper order to watch the various *Babylon 5* episodes and TV movies.

Comment: This was my thought as well. This movie was also IMHO one of the better pieces of broadcast TV I've seen in my life. Also on that list is season 2's episode 20: The Long Twilight Struggle.

Comment: About Centauri similarity to humans, isn't there a mention of backstory in which the Centauri tried to get humanity to believe we're related (although they know it's false)?

Comment: @AntonSherwood **Minbari**. And [it's not false](https://youtu.be/v5Usu5kD6gI) (spoilers).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Wrong. When the Minbari became aware of it, they called off the war, *and never said why*.

Comment: @AntonSherwood Oh, you meant the line about how after first contact with Londo's people they tried to imply that humans were a lost branch. I vaguely remember that line, and I think it was Sinclair talking to Londo. Guess I have to watch Babylon 5 from the beginning again (oh darn).

Answer (score 48):

This could be the 1990s TV show [Babylon 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5)

> Spaceship like Star Trek.

LOTS of spaceships

> Alien spaceships have 4 legs?

The spaceships of the Shadows (an alien race) kind of have lots of leg-like appendages:
[image]

> The story is about the fight between the human race with an alien species,The human race is almost annihilated. They lost every fight but keep fighting to the last man. But the alien stop the attack..

Part of the back story to the show is that the humans had been in a war with an alien race, the Minbari. The Minbari nearly wipe out the humans but call off the war at the last moment.

> an alien species (which had something like coral attach to their head)

Like this?

[image]

> the humans build something like a satellite.

At the start of the series the humans have just built the eponymous space station "Babylon 5":

[image]

Comment: Thank. Look like the film I watched is `in the beginning` from babylon5 series.

Comment: Good IDs.  One suggestion: Vorlon ships (four legs) seem like a closer match than Shadow vessels (many legs).

Comment: @someoneuseless If you just caught *that one movie* on TV randomly, that's tragic.  You might want to watch the whole Babylon-5 series, then. Like a lot of shows (ST:TNG, Buffy) the first season is rocky, but then, [lookout](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/6ba4du/til_growing_the_beard_is_the_polar_opposite_of/).  It was one of the defining moments in the [(new) "Golden Age of Television"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Age_of_Television_(2000s%E2%80%93present)), when TV started to get *good*.

Comment: @Harper worth mentioning that Babylon-5 started the pattern that nearly every current TV show has come to use, the idea of telling a single coherent highly scripted story in a series of episodes (Before B5 nearly all fictional TV shows were designed such that they could be shown in any order and you couldn't really tell which came first).

Comment: Yes! Please do watch all of Bablylon 5, but note: Straczynski initially wrote & pitched the show as a 5-season plot. That's how it started, but after season 3 it was canned with season 4 becoming the final season. He therefore had to rush to the end of his plot one season early… **then** it got a reprieve, 11th hour, so season 5 has an oddly anti-climatic 'what the heck do we do now?'  feel to it.

Comment: contd… This is covered briefly in the 'Writing' section at [Wikipedia-Babylon 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5#Writing) [I hadn't realised the TV station went out of business, I came to the story late]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is G.O.R.A. Aliens kidnap humankind and enslave them. G.O.R.A is the name of the planet where aliens came from. You can reach it from here
[G.O.R.A.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.O.R.A.)